# How do I restrict <input type=number> to pure numbers on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a registration form that has an input type = "number" that restricts entry to pure numbers; meaning no comma, dot or dash. On desk top my control works fine. When the form is displayed on mobile (android), the numeric keyboard displays, and the user is able to enter the dot and dash characters. The user is not able to enter comma.

The input tag is:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="only_number_here" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);">
```

The JavaScript code is below:

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `12.34` is a number. You mean non-negative integers only? (Or digit characters only.)

Comment: You should look at the actual character typed (i.e. the value of the input), not [*event.which*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) or  [*event.keyCode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), both of which are deprecated.

Comment: can you post the navigator.userAgent of the android browser your testing on

Comment: Yes, the entry is for positive integers only. The navigator.userAgent is Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; CAM-L21 Build/HUAWEICAM-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: did yu got a solution/workaround for this?. I want only postiive integers too

Comment: I have been trying to dig around to find a solution for this, but haven't found a solution yet.